# Compare timestamp with range of timestamps

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have event_timestamp in next query:

```
 SELECT COUNT(id) = 0 as "isEmpty" 
 FROM status 
 WHERE id = 22 
   AND event_timestamp > user_timestamp
```

Now I can't use condition `event_timestamp > user_timestamp`, because instead `user_timestamp` I have range of timestamps.
Like:

```
id   start_user_timestamp        end_user_timestamp
22   2021-05-02 11:23:59.02343   2021-05-04 21:43:39.02343
22   2021-06-01 13:23:59.02343   2021-06-04 13:43:59.02343
22   2021-07-01 23:43:59.02343   2021-07-04 23:43:59.02343
```

What is the best way to check is `event_timestamp` bigger than start/end values?

Comment: So you want to check if `user_timestamp` falls into the range defined by start/end? Or do you want to check if `user_timestamp` is bigger than **both** values?

Comment: check if user_timestamp is bigger than both values

Comment: As you have a range value, I suppose that `end_user_timestamp` is always bigger than `start_user_timestamp`. If yes, you can only check if event_timestamp is bigger than `end_user_timestamp`. You don't need to check both values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an AND condition to compare both columns

```
SELECT COUNT(id) = 0 as "isEmpty" 
 FROM status 
 WHERE id = 22 
   AND user_timestamp > start_user_timestamp
   AND user_timestamp > end_user_timestamp
```